# Cannot reset password on Azure Linux VM using Resource Manager (ARM) model

Tags: powershell, azure

I have an Ubuntu VM setup under the Azure Resource Manager (ARM) model that, after an unexpected reboot, I have lost access to as the existing password magically stopped working. After trying to replicate the [classic mode Azure Powershell method](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-use-vmaccess-reset-password-or-ssh/#password) with the [equivalent ARM model commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34364158/get-azurevm-returns-nothing-tried-suggestions) and having absolutely no luck (because I don't understand what I'm doing, above all) I'm trying to use the Azure CLI to reset the password [as outlined here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/motiba/archive/2015/11/29/how-to-reset-the-password-windows-azure-arm-based-vm.aspx). After logging in and setting config mode to arm, `reset-access` does run to completion:

[image]

but the chosen password still does not work. Azure CLI is not my forte, and I'm pretty much stumped now. What could I possibly be doing wrong here?

Comment: It there's one thing I'm good at on Server Fault, it's asking questions that no one wants to answer.

Comment: I cant reset my password, i forgot it tho

Comment: Epilogue: Ultimately I had to blow away the VM and recreate it. I never managed to figure out why this happened.